# How to populate the users with the posts that have the user's id in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating my first MERN application, and I've come to this problem: 
I have the posts that hold the user id:

```
{
    "reward": {
        ...
    },
    "_id": "5eb2d90d7d56c415cc4d5f97",
    "user": "5eabbb85b8814723fcee0f01",
    "text": "Body text hihi hahha",
    "createdAt": "2020-05-06T15:34:37.439Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I did manage to automatically add a user id to the post when creating in the post controller. Now the problem is that I don't know where and how I should push the id of the created post in an array of posts in the user model. 
This is what the User model:

```
    username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Username is required"],
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 3,
    maxlength: 15,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Email is required"],
    unique: true,
  },
  role: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["user"],
    default: "user",
  },
  cards: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: "Card"
    },
  ],
```

And right there where the "cards" are, I would like to have the id's of the posts that hold the id of the user in the user field.
This is the Post model:

```
    user: String,
  text: {
    type: String,
  },
  reward: {
    ...
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: true
  },
```

This is the controller for saving the post to the database:

```
exports.addCard = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    //Add user to req.body
    req.body.user = req.user.id;

    const card = await Card.create(req.body);

    res.status(201).json({
        success: true, 
        message: 'Card created', 
        data: card
    });
});
```

I am guessing that it should happen when creating the post, something like pushing that post id in array of posts in the user modal of the current logged in user ? 
How can that be correctly archived ?

Comment: could you show us the code where you save a post to the database?

Comment: Sure, I edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a second query to insert the `_id`.

Make sure that the `_id` at `$match` is a ObjectId like `ObjectId("5d345234daa45")` and not `5d345234daa45`

```
exports.addCard = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    //Add user to req.body
    req.body.user = req.user.id;

    const card = await Card.create(req.body);

    const id = card._id; // this should be your _id,  check with console.log() if this is your _id

    //dont forget to import your model 
    await User.update({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.user) },
       {
          $push: {
             cards: id
          }
       });


    res.status(201).json({
        success: true, 
        message: 'Card created', 
        data: card
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks like something I would need! But I get the error '$push is not allowed in this atlas tier'. Is there an alternative to it  ?

Comment: @Samuel i updatet it, it is `update` not `aggregate`